# How to use awk separator of single quote?

Tags: unix, awk, escape-characters

I'd like to use awk to pull out information from SQL output like the following:

> (count(distinct serverclass)='2')

And need to extract the number, which is 2 in this example.

I'd like to do something like the following, but cannot figure out how to escape the single quote:

```
<sqlCommand> | awk 'BEGIN{FS="'"}{print $2}'
```

How can I get a literal single quote as my field separator in awk?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To insert a single quote character in a single-quoted string, end the current string, write `"'"` or `\'` and begin the string again.

In your example, that's

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="'"'"'"}{print $2}'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="'\''"}{print $2}'
```

However, using the `-F` switch to specify the field separator will result in more legible code:

```
awk -F\' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Why did you update the style from `-F"'"` to `-F\'`?

Comment: No good reason. Both work, but the first has too many quotes for my taste.